# how to find the number of consecutive repeats

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to write a mysql script to find the number of consecutive repeats in 'value' column of this table.

```
id    value    result
--    -----    ------
1      1        0
2      1        1
3      2        0
4      3        0
5      3        1
```

So in this case I want get the value 2

Comment: What is your ordering criteria?

Comment: Do we care about `result` column at all?

Comment: I already ordered it by id @Burhan Khalid

Comment: result column show the result I want @PM 77-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next value using user variables,
  GROUP so consecutive values more than 2 are not counted again,put all in a subquery,and use a simple CASE to increment the value you need in case value=next value.Add salt and pepper.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN y.value=y.next_value THEN @var+1 ELSE @var END) consecIds
    FROM
    (SELECT t.id, t.value, next_id, n.value next_value
      FROM
    (
      SELECT t.id, t.value,

      (
        SELECT id
          FROM table1
         WHERE id > t.id
         ORDER BY id
         LIMIT 1
      ) next_id
        FROM table1 t,(SELECT @var:=0)x
    ) t LEFT JOIN table1 n

         ON t.next_id = n.id 
         GROUP BY t.value,n.value)y
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/942e7/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. It probably is right since it works in FIDDLE, but somehow it doesn't work on my computer. I have to check to errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

DISTINCT will erase duplicated repetitions from specified column in result.

COUNT will count the rows in result.

The COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) function returns the number of distinct values of the specified column.